# Mattermost Create Channel from curl command

Tags: curl, mattermost

I have setup Mattermost create channel github api on my website.
Please provide curl command to create the a new channel.

I have tried below but it fails

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'Authorization:Bearer (removed)' -X POST -d -H {"display_name":"testviaCurl","name":"testViaCurl","team_id":"(removed)","purpose":"","type":"O"} http://zzz.zzz.co/api/v1/channels/create
```

Let me know if the syntax is incorrect?

Comment: Please do not ask others to do the work for you. Instead explain your problem, what you have tried so far and detailed error descriptions. Also, never publicly post access tokens etc. Cleanup your examples from tokens, passwords etc.

Comment: Please see the curl command which I had already posted along with my query and see if you can help or tell me what is wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a misplaced `-H` and you're missing quotes around your data.

This worked for me on Mattermost 2.2:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer yourtokenhere" -X POST -d '{"display_name":"testviaCurl","name":"testviacurl","team_id":"yourteamid","purpose":"","type":"O"}' http://yourmattermostinstance.com/api/v1/channels/create
```

For Mattermost 3.0+, this should work:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer yourtokenhere" -X POST -d '{"display_name":"testviaCurl","name":"testviacurl","team_id":"yourteamid","purpose":"","type":"O"}' http://yourmattermostinstance.com/api/v3/teams/<yourteamid>/channels/create
```

Also note that I lower cased the value for the `name` JSON field since Mattermost rejects names with uppercases.